# Ktor HttpClient is hang in runBlocking

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I am validating App Store recipes in a server-side Kotlin using with Ktor's `HttpClient` (Ktor version is 1.2.1). Here is my code so far:

```
class AppStoreClient(
        val url: String,
        val password: String,
        val excludeOldTransactions: Boolean = true
) {
    private val objectMapper = ObjectMapperFactory.defaultObjectMapper()
    private val client = HttpClient(Apache /* tried with CIO as well */) {
        install(JsonFeature) {
            serializer = JacksonSerializer()
        }
    }

    suspend fun validate(receipt: String): VerifyReceiptResponse {
        val post = client.post<String> {
            url(this@AppStoreClient.url)
            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
            accept(ContentType.Application.Json)
            body = VerifyReceiptRequest(
                    receipt,
                    password,
                    excludeOldTransactions
            )
        }

        // client.close()

        // Apple does not send Content-Type header ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
        // So Ktor's deserialization is not working here and
        // I have to manually deserialize the response.
        return objectMapper.readValue(post)
    }
}
```

And here I'm testing it:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val client = AppStoreClient("https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt", "<password>")

    println(client.validate("<recipe1>"))
    // println(client.validate("<recipe2>"))
    // println(client.validate("<recipe3>"))
}
```

I got all the responses (one or three) in the output, but then my app just hangs and never quits the `main` method. Looks like `runBlocking` is still waiting for something, like `client.close`. Indeed, if I close the client after the first request, the app successfully ends, but that will force me to create the client on each separate validation request. Client's pipeline configuration seems to be time-consuming and `AppStoreClient` is meant to be a long-lived object, so I thought the client can share its lifecycle (probably even dependency-injected).

Is the `io.ktor.client.HttpClient` a long-lived object that can be re-used for multiple requests or should I create a new one for each request?

If yes, what am I doing wrong with it, so the `runBlocking` hangs?

---

P.S. The code works with Ktor 1.1.1! Is it a bug?

---

P.P.S. This code hangs as well:

```
fun main() {
    val client = AppStoreClient("...", "...")

    runBlocking {
        println(client.validate("..."))
        println(client.validate("..."))
        println(client.validate("..."))
    }

    runBlocking {
        println(client.validate("..."))
        println(client.validate("..."))
        println(client.validate("..."))
    }
}
```

So I might seriously consider closing the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the io.ktor.client.HttpClient a long-lived object that can be re-used for multiple requests or should I create a new one for each request?

Yes, it's recommended to use single HttpClient, since some resources (like thread-pool in case of ApacheHttpClient) allocated under the hood, and there are no reasons to create new client each time.

> If yes, what am I doing wrong with it, so the runBlocking hangs?

Your problem with closing client, not with coroutines itself, consider this example which also "hangs":

```
fun main() {
    val client = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault().also {
        it.start()
    }
}
```

So in my practice, closing client responsibility of developer, like this:

```
fun main() {
    val client = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault().also {
        it.start()
    }

    client.close() // we're good now

}
```

Or using `Runtime.addShutodownHook` in more complex applications.

> P.S. The code works with Ktor 1.1.1! Is it a bug?

I think this is real question, what 1.1.1 do, that 1.2.1 don't (or visa-versa)

---

**UPD**.

According Ktor Client [documentation](https://ktor.io/clients/http-client.html), you should close client manually:

```
suspend fun sequentialRequests() {
    val client = HttpClient()

    // Get the content of an URL.
    val firstBytes = client.get<ByteArray>("https://127.0.0.1:8080/a")

    // Once the previous request is done, get the content of an URL.
    val secondBytes = client.get<ByteArray>("https://127.0.0.1:8080/b")

    client.close()
}
```